# M.2 M-key SSD but Sata Slot?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sata, pci-express, nvme

M.2 Slot
1x 2280 SATA M.2 (M key) slot

This is the listed spec for my laptop model. When I open my laptop, the slot is also a pure m key slot.

I did some research and it mentioned m-key slots are mostly used with nvme drives on pci-e. However when I tried inserting my Samsung Evo m2 SSD, it wasn't recognized in my com. Not drive mgmt, not within bios as well. Tried diskpart but no drive detected as well.

So now I'm considering if I should get a m.2 sata m+b key drive for my laptop and if it will work for my case.

Picture of the slot on the laptop. I'm using a travelmate p648 series.
[image: m.2 slot picture]

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer but for those who are seeking.

--

Should I Choose M.2 M or B+M Key SSD?

When you plan to buy an M.2 SSD, you must take M.2 slot into consideration. In a computer, there is only an M.2 B-key socket or an M.2 M-key socket, but no M.2 B+M key socket.

Before you buy an M.2 SSD, you should check which type of slot your computer is using. An M.2 B key slot is only compatible with B+M key SSDs, and an M.2 M key slot is compatible with both B+M key SSD and M key SSD.

The last but not least, you should check whether the M.2 slot supports PCIe (check in motherboard information). If it is PCI Express, please check whether it supports 2x or 4x PCI-Express. After getting these details, you can then buy an M.2 SSD without worries.

--quoted: https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmanager/m2-m-vs-bm.html

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.